# relate 2 columns of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following 2 tables in Mysql:

```
table name:store (store user id's)
emp dst
1    2
1    3
2    1
3    1
4    2

table name:users
id   name
1    empA
2    empB
3    empC
4    empD
```

How should my query be to obtain the following result based on the store table?

```
result
emp  dst
empA empB
empA empC
empB empA
empC empA
empD empB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just join `store` and `users` together. But you should join `users` twice as you want names for both emp and dst.

So the query might be:

```
SELECT u1.name AS emp, u2.name AS dst 
FROM store AS s 
JOIN users AS u1 ON s.emp = u1.id 
JOIN users AS u2 ON s.dst = u2.id;
```

Comment: It's a pleasure.